# Is the Spanish present tense ever (correctly) translated into English as simple past tense?

Tags: traducción, tiempos-verbales

This question came to mind when I recently spotted the phrase **"no me doy por vencido."**  I was already somewhat familiar with the phrase **"darse por vencido"** (to give up), so I had an idea of what it meant, but I wanted to be sure, so I looked the phrase up in Reverso.  **[What I found there](https://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/no+me+doy+por+vencido#)** rather confused me and raised questions I could not easily find an answer to, so I decided to post a question here.

What I discovered is that the first meaning listed for **"no me doy por vencido"** was

> **"I didn't give up."**

I was a bit surprised to see this, so I immediately ran a few other searches and discovered that there are other, more common ways of translating, "I didn't give up" (e.g., "no me rendí").  Be that as it may, I wanted to know why the past tense was such a common translation for this present tense phrase.  I already know that tenses don't always translate into identical tenses between languages, but I had thought that translations from present tense were limited to continuous, progressive, and future tense.  To date, I had never seen a present tense Spanish verb construction translated into the past tense, especially the preterite (aside from idiomatic expressions such as "hace tiempo que ...").  Can anyone explain why Reverso lists "I didn't give up" as the first translation for "no me doy por vencido?"

Furthermore, is

> **"No me doy por vencido,"**

completely interchangeable with either of the following:

> **"No me di por vencido," or**
>   **"No me daba por vencido."**

If these are considered correct translations (of "I didn't give up"), can anyone tell me whether or not this is more common with certain verbs or give me an idea of how often this occurs in Spanish to English translations — translating Spanish present tense into English simple past tense?

---

*Addendum*

BTW, I would be remiss if I didn't somehow find a way to include mention of Luis Fonsi's "**[No Me Doy Por Vencido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Me_Doy_por_Vencido)**."  If you do not live in a Spanish-speaking country, you might have missed it, but the song was extremely popular back in 2008 and I'd bet most Spanish speakers know of it.  I include it here because I've looked at the translated lyrics for this song and watched the official video for it.  Clearly "no me doy por vencido" refers to the present or future, but definitely not the past.  The video seems to carry a message of hope, strength, and resilience  ... no matter what the circumstances, even though that's a bit of a departure from the actual lyrics (which would fall squarely into the category "romantic ballad").  **[LyricsTranslate](https://lyricstranslate.com/en)** is my first choice when I want to see translated lyrics for a song.  For popular songs, there's usually more than one translation into English, but the quality can vary from "what a way with words!" to "even I could have done better."  For "No Me Doy Por Vencido," you will find four English translations.  IMHO, #2 is best and you can link to it **[here](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/no-me-doy-por-vencido-i-wont-surrender.html)**.  As for the video, I would have embedded it below for those who have never heard the song or seen the video, but it doesn't look as if that is an option, so instead you can view it by clicking on the link below:

[**Luis Fonsi - No Me Doy Por Vencido (Official Music Video)**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hRGBcr_gJc)

---

**¿Alguna vez se traduce (correctamente) el tiempo presente español al inglés como pasado simple?**

Esta pregunta vino a la mente cuando recientemente vi la frase **"no me doy por vencido."** Ya más o menos sabía la frase **"darse por vencido"** (to give up), así que tuve una idea de qué significaba, pero quería estar segura, así que busqué la frase en Reverso.  **[Lo que encontré allí](https://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/no+me+doy+por+vencido#)** me confundió y provocaba preguntas de las que no podía encontrar fácilmente, así que decidí publica una pregunta aquí.

Lo que descubrí es que la primera traducción enumerada para **"no me doy por vencido"** fue

> **I didn't give up.**

Me sorprendió ver esta así que inmediatamente busqué por las traducciones de otras frases similares y descubrí que hay otras formas más comunes de traducir, "I didn't give up" (p.ej., "no me rendí").  Sea como fuere, quería saber por qué el tiempo pasado era una traducción tan común para esta frase en tiempo presente.  Ya sé que los tiempos no siempre traducen a los tiempos identicales entre los idiomas, pero había pensado que con las traducciones del tiempo presente se limitaron a tiempo continuo, progresivo y futuro.  Hasta la fecha, nunca había visto una construcción del verbo español en el tiempo presente traducida al tiempo pasado, especialmente al pretérito (aparte de las expresiones idiomáticas como "hace tiempo que ...").  ¿Puede alguien explicar por qué Reverso enumera "I didn't give up" como la primera traducción para "no me doy por vencido"?

Asimismo, ¿es

> **"No me doy por vencido",**

completamente intercambiablemente con cualquiera de las siguientes oraciones:

> **"No me di por vencido",**
>   **"No me daba por vencido".**

Si se consideran traducciones correctas (de "I didn't give up"), ¿puede alguien decirme  si esto es más común con ciertos verbos o me da una idea con qué frecencia esto ocurre  en traducciones de español al inglés — traduciendo tiempo presente español al pretérito en inglés?

---

---

*Suplemento*

Por cierto, sería una negligencia si, de alguna manera, no encontraba una oportunidad para mencionar "**[No Me Doy Por Vencido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_me_doy_por_vencido)**" por Luis Fonsi.  Si no vives en un país hispanohablante, es posible que te pasó por alto, pero la canción era extremadamente popular en 2008 y apostaría a que la mayoría de hispanohablantes la conocen.  Lo incluyo aquí porque he mirado en las letras traducidas de esta canción y he visto el vídeo oficial para ella.  Claramente, "no me doy por vencido" refiere al presente o futuro, pero definitivamente no el pasado.  El vídeo parece transmitir un mensaje de esperanza, fuerza y resilencia ... sin importar las circunstancias, aunque es un poco de una desviación de las letras verdaderas (que corresponde plenamente a la categoría "balada romántica").  **[LyricsTranslate](https://lyricstranslate.com/en)** es mi primera opción cuando quiero ver letras traducidas de una canción.  De canciones populares, normalmente hay más que una traducción al inglés, pero la calidad puede variar de "¡qué facilidad con las palabras!" a "incluso yo podría haberlo hecho mejor".  Para esta canción, encontrarás cuatro traducciones inglesas.  En mi humilde opinión, #2 es la mejor y puedes enlazar a ella **[aquí](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/no-me-doy-por-vencido-i-wont-surrender.html)**.  En cuanto al vídeo, habría incrustado el vídeo a continuación, pero no parece que esa es una opción, así que en lugar de eso, puedes verlo haciendo clic en enlace por debajo:

**[Luis Fonsi - No Me Doy Por Vencido (Official Music Video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hRGBcr_gJc)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the Reverso examples do translate Spanish present tense to English present (simple or continuous). The ones that translate as past ("I didn't give up") look like mistakes to me; bear in mind Reverso feeds on actual texts from many sources, which are not necessarily curated translations. If you take a look at the context of these particular examples, you'll see that they come from movie subtitles. The original subtitles are in English; the translation is **to**, not **from** Spanish, and it's a very bad translation (in the first one, for example, "Words won" is translated as *Palabras ganó*).

If anything, *no me doy por vencido* could actually sometimes be translated into English as future: "I won't give up". This usage of the *w-* modal verb is in fact idiomatic; it stands for unmodifiable intent (reflecting the original meaning of *will* as "want, wish"). Since *darse por vencido* can be either a one-time action or an enduring state, *no me doy por vencido* can be translated as "I'm not giving up (right now)" or "I won't (intend to) give up (and I'm keeping up my stance)".

There are contexts where both present and past could work in Spanish, but they're not the same. *Darse por vencido* is not a fixed phrase; it's an idiom where the verb follows the habitual rules.

Comment: Really great answers from both you and @walen and it makes me wish I could award two green check marks, but alas, there's only one to give and it will go to you, pablodf76.  Both of you answered my question(s), but you cleared up for me why I might see a poor translation from Reverso, and, consequently, I likely won't feel a need to post a question in the future based off of something I see on Reverso that doesn't mesh with my base of understanding about the Spanish language.

Comment: Then, even more than that, you go into great detail in the second paragraph, but in a way that even non-linguists would find interesting and easy to understand.  And the last two lines assure me that what I saw at Reverso needn't change my thinking about how the Spanish language is used.  Well done and, once again, well deserved.  Mil gracias, pablodf76.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Alguna vez se traduce (correctamente) el tiempo presente español al inglés como pasado simple?

En general, no.

Un caso especial podría ser cuando se usa el presente narrativo.
Por ejemplo, si dices *«Estoy comprando flores, y de repente aparece Juan. ¡Me hizo mucha ilusión verle!»* para contar algo que te sucedió **ayer**, podrías traducirlo usando el pasado simple (*I was buying flowers, and suddenly Juan appeared. I was so happy to see him!*); aunque se perdería el recurso estilístico, la traducción seguiría siendo correcta.

Pero en general, no. El ejemplo que indicas parece incorrecto.

> ¿Es "**No me doy por vencido**", completamente intercambiablemente con cualquiera de las siguientes oraciones: "**No me di por vencido**", "**No me daba por vencido**"?

Lo mismo que antes: en general no, no son intercambiables. Las dos oraciones en pasado están describiendo una acción pasada, mientras que la oración en presente podría tanto estar describiendo una acción que está sucediendo (*He suspendido el examen pero no me doy por vencido*), como una característica de quien habla (*Soy muy perseverante, no me doy por vencido fácilmente*).

Solo en el caso de que se esté usando el presente para describir dicha acción pasada, es decir, el presente narrativo, podría sustituirse una por la otra.
Ejemplo: *Estaba ayer en el mercado y entonces veo a Maluma. El tío nada más verme sale corriendo, pero yo no me doy por vencido y salgo corriendo detrás... Al final le alcancé y me firmó un autógrafo en el brazo.*